# How to do for loop in xarray python and create multi dataset with different days?

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop, dataset, python-xarray

I have list of Timestamp of different days (day_of_tuple_3Days) and I want to select each day with previous 7 days and after 7 days to create dataset of each case ,How can I do that ?
my could is :

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
n = 0

current_date = day_of_tuple_3Days[n].isoformat()   
days_before = (day_of_tuple_3Days[n]-timedelta(days=7)).isoformat()
days_after = (day_of_tuple_3Days[n]+timedelta(days=7)).isoformat()  

case = study_area.sel(time = slice(days_before,days_after))
```

where day_of_tuple_3Days is :

```
[Timestamp('2000-07-15 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2000-08-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2002-07-20 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2003-08-10 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2007-07-30 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2010-07-13 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2010-08-13 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2011-08-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2012-07-24 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-08-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2016-07-22 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2017-07-05 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2017-07-18 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2017-07-23 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2017-08-09 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2018-07-04 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2018-07-10 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-06-26 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-08-01 00:00:00')]
```

and I expected that :
case0
case1
case2
and so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your list of `Timestamp`s into a list of strings, and do:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
from pandas import DataFrame

times = ['2000-07-15 00:00:00',
         '2000-08-02 00:00:00',
         '2002-07-20 00:00:00',
         '2003-08-10 00:00:00',
         '2007-07-30 00:00:00',
         '2010-07-13 00:00:00',
         '2010-08-13 00:00:00',
         '2011-08-02 00:00:00',
         '2012-07-24 00:00:00',
         '2015-08-01 00:00:00',
         '2016-07-22 00:00:00',
         '2017-07-05 00:00:00',
         '2017-07-18 00:00:00',
         '2017-07-23 00:00:00',
         '2017-08-09 00:00:00',
         '2018-07-04 00:00:00',
         '2018-07-10 00:00:00',
         '2019-06-26 00:00:00',
         '2019-08-01 00:00:00']

results = dict()
days = timedelta(7)
for i, t in enumerate(times, 1):
    y, m, d = map(int, t[:10].split('-'))
    da = date(y, m, d)
    before = da - days
    after = da + days
    results[f'case{i}'] = [f'{before} to {da}', f'{da} to {after}']

print(results)
```

Output:

```
{'case1': ['2000-07-08 to 2000-07-15', '2000-07-15 to 2000-07-22'],
 'case2': ['2000-07-26 to 2000-08-02', '2000-08-02 to 2000-08-09'],
 'case3': ['2002-07-13 to 2002-07-20', '2002-07-20 to 2002-07-27'],
 'case4': ['2003-08-03 to 2003-08-10', '2003-08-10 to 2003-08-17'],
 'case5': ['2007-07-23 to 2007-07-30', '2007-07-30 to 2007-08-06'],
 'case6': ['2010-07-06 to 2010-07-13', '2010-07-13 to 2010-07-20'],
 'case7': ['2010-08-06 to 2010-08-13', '2010-08-13 to 2010-08-20'],
 'case8': ['2011-07-26 to 2011-08-02', '2011-08-02 to 2011-08-09'],
 'case9': ['2012-07-17 to 2012-07-24', '2012-07-24 to 2012-07-31'],
 'case10': ['2015-07-25 to 2015-08-01', '2015-08-01 to 2015-08-08'],
 'case11': ['2016-07-15 to 2016-07-22', '2016-07-22 to 2016-07-29'],
 'case12': ['2017-06-28 to 2017-07-05', '2017-07-05 to 2017-07-12'],
 'case13': ['2017-07-11 to 2017-07-18', '2017-07-18 to 2017-07-25'],
 'case14': ['2017-07-16 to 2017-07-23', '2017-07-23 to 2017-07-30'],
 'case15': ['2017-08-02 to 2017-08-09', '2017-08-09 to 2017-08-16'],
 'case16': ['2018-06-27 to 2018-07-04', '2018-07-04 to 2018-07-11'],
 'case17': ['2018-07-03 to 2018-07-10', '2018-07-10 to 2018-07-17'],
 'case18': ['2019-06-19 to 2019-06-26', '2019-06-26 to 2019-07-03'],
 'case19': ['2019-07-25 to 2019-08-01', '2019-08-01 to 2019-08-08']}
```

Comment: the answer of this solution this 1564610400.0 !!

Comment: @hasanainkhalil Can you clarify your question? What are the `Timestamp()` classes? Please provide code that can be ran without an error.

Comment: The list (day_of_tuple_3Days) is single days .For each day I must select -7days before and +7 after from the calendar for example the fist day in the list is 2000-07-15 so the period should be selected is 2000-07-07 to 2000-07-15 and from 2000-07-15 to 2000-07-21 that is done by the timedelta  , the point that how can I do for loop to select each day in list  and then select the days before and after from the calendar and make of each consecutive days data array such as case1,case2,case3 ....

Comment: @hasanainkhalil Is my edit what you are trying to do?